# Elements in two columns with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, multiple-columns

I want to visualize a set of elements in two columns. When the number of elements exceed the available space I would like to see a vertical scroll-bar.

Here the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="box"> box 1</div>
 <div class="box"> box 2</div>
 <div class="box"> box 3</div>
 <div class="box"> box 4</div>
 <div class="box"> box 5</div>
 <div class="box"> box 6</div>
 <div class="box"> box 7</div>
 <div class="box"> box 8</div>
 <div class="box"> box 9</div>
 <div class="box"> box 10</div>
 <div class="box"> box 11</div>
 <div class="box"> box 12</div>
</div>
```

Here the CSS:

```
.container {
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 100px;

 -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 2;
}

.box {
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 100px;
}
```

The JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fedy2/7m7xqdoh/3/).

When the elements are 10 or less the rendering is fine.

When the elements are more than 10 the remaining are rendered out of the container on the right side. I would like instead to see a vertical scroll-bar for the container and have the elements distributed like 1-6 in column 1 and 7-12 in column 2.

It is possible to have such distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `max-height` and then add an `overflow-y: scroll` to allow the container to scroll.  `overflow-x: hidden` is to remove the vertical scrollbar.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7xqdoh/5/)

**Example**

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The container height should be fixed.